# Problem with sorting list of strings properly

Tags: python, string, sorting

I wrote simple list of elements then I sort it out but, the sorted list is:

```
lis = ["P1","P3","P4","P11","P22"]
lis.sort()
print(lis)
```

The output will be:

```
['P1', 'P11', 'P22', 'P3', 'P4']
```

but I would expected list:

```
['P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P11', 'P22']
```

as the `11` and `22` are bigger than `3` and `4`.

I know that it is string list but can I do it somehow?

Comment: Python sort functions take a key function. Make a function that turns your string into a number and pass it to `key=`.

Comment: Suggest you take a peek at the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the fine documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
lis = ["P1","P3","P4","P11","P22"]
lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('P')[-1]))
print(lis)

# ["P1","P3","P4","P11","P22"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all your strings have this same format of `P` followed by a number, then just remove the `P` and convert to `int`.

```py
lis = ["P1","P3","P4","P11","P22"]
lis.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1:]))
print(lis)

# ['P1', 'P3', 'P4', 'P11', 'P22']
```

If the more general case where you don't know the format of the strings, but want to sort using what is commonly referred to as **natural sort**, you can use [module **natsort**](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/):

```py
import natsort
lis = ['Alice11C', 'Bob10', 'Alice2B', 'Bob9']
print(natsort.natsorted(lis))

# ['Alice2B', 'Alice11C', 'Bob9', 'Bob10']
```